# my model is predicting all positive class to negative class in libsvm toolbox matlab

Tags: matlab, libsvm, classification

I created a classifier using libsvm toolbox in Matlab. It is classifying all positive class data as negative class and vice versa. I got good result while doing cross validation but while testing some data I am finding that classifier is working in wrong way. I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies.

Can anybody please help me on this matter.

Comment: Is the classifier predicting exactly reverse? If yes, then it will be an evaluation issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes it is predicting exactly reverse. Could you kindly let me know how to solve it.

Comment: That means the category 0 in training has become category 1 (by mistake). Its just an evaluation issue. Check if you have followed the exact same protocols in training and testing. Somewhere you will find a fault.

Comment: thanks a lot. I did not get what you mean by 'protocol'. I cheked my input files , they are ok, I am using matlab libsvm. There I just need to feed data and they do the rest. I only used command to train dataset, create model, test dataset on that model. Here I should mension that for training and testing I am using same dataset. For example if I am using 1-900 instances for training then using rest 400 instances for testing. I would be grateful if you kindly help me some more. I am really stucked.

Comment: @syeda-firdaus: Do I understand you correctly: you have exactly 0% accuracy?

Comment: while doing cross validation i am getting good accuracy. while doing testing i m also getting good accuracy but no. of TP are showing as TN. Like #TP + #FN = should be # of actual positives but showing total # of actual negatives and vise versa.

Comment: again I would say that maybe is a labelling issue... but if you are so confident, then sorry, I won't be able to help you further. If you find the fault, please post it back here.

Answer (score 2):

This was a "feature" of prior versions of libsvm when the first training example's (binary) label was -1. The easiest solution is to get the latest version (> 3.17).

See here for more details: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f430

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 500 training instances. 250 will be positive and other negative. Now in the testing set, the instances which have same features as positive will get predicted as positive. But when you are supplying testing labels (you have to provide testing labels so that LIBSVM can calculate accuracy, they won't obviously be used in the preiction algorithm) to LIBSVM, you have provided exactly reverse labels (by mistake). So you have a feeling that your predicted labels have come out exactly opposite. Because even a random classifier will have a 50% accuracy for a binary classification problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply. I have total 1600 instances, 443 were with positive labels, rest were with negative labels. from those I am using 300 positive as training set and  rest 143 dataset for testing . I kept the data for tesing with labels. I used 400 negative instances for training and 200 dataset for testing. Finally When I tested with all 343 dbataset for tesing. all positive and negatives are properly labeled. After testing I am getting total opposite result. like poisities are predicted as negative and vise versa. Could you please help me further.